# How to assign value of array element by a arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arrow-functions, object-destructuring

I need to set one of the array property using arrow function. In my sample code I have added random key and an arrow function. but when I console the output, I cant see the "random" key. Can this be done using arrow functions.

```js
let Allitems = {"items":[{"id":74489},{"id":64489},{"id":53489}]};

const newarr = Allitems.items.map(e => ({...e, name:"newnamme", random: (e) => { return e.id + "random"; } }));
 console.log(newarr);
```

```
// expected output
{"items":[ 
{"id":74489,name:"newnamme", random : "74489random"},
{"id":64489,name:"newnamme", random : "64489random"},
{"id":53489,name:"newnamme", random : "53489random"}]
}
```

Comment: Can you make it a runnable stack snippet or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS Its already there!

Answer (score 5):

What you probably want is an [immediately invoked function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
let Allitems = {"items":[{"id":74489},{"id":64489},{"id":53489}]};

const newarr = Allitems.items.map(e => ({
    ...e,
    name:"newnamme",
    random: ((e) => { return e.id + "random"; })(e)
}));
 console.log(newarr);
```